# "true" or true which is more proper

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a technical question which need expert advise.  I have a data in the database which is a string "true".  But when I retrieve it to test the condition, which one is more advisable to use even though they both work.

```
if ($data == true)
```

or

```
if ($data == "true")
```

My gut feeling is use "true" to test if the value stored is a string and use true without the quotes when the database value is stored as a boolean.  But want to confirm with you guys.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed, at least almost. You're right to check the data-type as well, however in PHP you need to use the `===` operator for that:

```
if ($data === TRUE) # boolean
if ($data === "true") # string
```

It's called the [*identical* operator <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and it compares the value *and* the type. Often helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a string then `$data == "true"` is what you want.

The expression `($data == true)` is equivalent to `($data)`, so it will evaluate to `true` even when `$data == "false"`

Answer (score 0):

The important case to understand is what the value will be from the database if the value is supposed to be `false`.

If the database returns `"false"`, and you check `$val == true` and `$val == "true"` only the latter will provide correct results.

You may need to consult the [php type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to be certain you understand what it is you're checking against.

Additionally, is there any chance that the database could return one of the following?

```
"true"
"True"
"TRUE"
"TrUe"
```

Just normalize or sanitize your database values (ideally, store binary values in a Boolean field so that this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`"false"==true` is true.

If your database has a column that only has the values of "true" or "false" then that is inefficient. Convert the column to a tinyint (or bool).

Otherwise, you should consider switching the string values of `"true"` and `"false"` to the boolean values of `true` and `false` when you pull them out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is stored literally as a string in the db, the second (`if ($data = "true")`) is what you want though they both will work. I suggest the second one for clarity.

You can test this out on the command using an interactive shell.

```
php -a
Interactive shell

php > $x = "true";
php > echo ($x == true) ? "True!" : "oops";
True!
php > echo ($x == "true") ? "True!" : "oops";
True!
php > echo ($x === "true") ? "True!" : "oops";
True!
php > echo ($x === true) ? "True!" : "oops";
oops
```

Note the effect that the `===` has. Since the value is a string they are not equal when using `===`.